# How to read "resource" files added via Tizen IDE

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-web-simulator

I'm giving my first steps on programming web apps for Tizen wearable devices . This is what I want to do :

1. By using the Tizen IDE , add a file , e.g. x.txt , under a folder ,
   e.g. data/text (i.e. relative path from project root is
   data/text/x.txt )
2. At run-time , I want to read the contents of x.txt
   file
3. ... and do some extra processing with it .

I thought I could just read `wgt-package` virtual root but [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712612/tizen-filesystem-resolve-error-the-content-of-an-object-does-not-include-val) (after fixing it) returns no file at that location .

How could I do this ? BTW , I've been testing on the web simulator .

p.s. I'm aware of the fact that this is quite simple , so guess this should be documented somewhere but I just could not find a reference after searching for a while (since yesterday), so I'm hoping someone can help me put my efforts on the right track

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

see, below FileSystem Tutorial and API Reference

FileSystem Tutorial https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/tizen-features/base/filesystem#retrieve

Filesystem API Reference https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html#FileSystemManager::resolve

If you put your text file on /project_root/data/text/x.txt.
You can access to that file with "wgt-package/data/text/x.txt" path on webapi.

So below is simple example code. try it.

```
 function onsuccess(files) {
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
     console.log("File Name is " + files[i].name); // displays file name

     if(file[i].name = "your_txt_file.txt"){
        //do something here. file[i].readAsText(....)
     }
   }
 }

 function onerror(error) {
   console.log("The error " + error.message + " occurred when listing the files in the selected folder");
 }

 tizen.filesystem.resolve(
     "wgt-package/data/text",
     function(dir) {
       documentsDir = dir; dir.listFiles(onsuccess,onerror);
     }, function(e) {
       console.log("Error" + e.message);
     }, "rw"
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your currently *working* code, so it is difficult to determine your exact problem. May be you are missing a privilege? `tizen.filesystem.resolve` requires `http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read`, you have to add it to your app config.

Anyhow, with `data/text/helloworld.txt` on my project folder, following sample code is working just fine:

```
var textFolder = "wgt-package/data/text";
var helloWorld = "helloworld.txt";

function onsuccess(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].name == helloWorld) {
            files[i].openStream("r", function(fs) {
                var text = fs.read(files[i].fileSize);
                fs.close();
                console.log("File contents: " + text);
            }, function(e) {
                console.log("Error " + e.message);
            }, "UTF-8");
            break;
        }
    }
}

    function onerror(error) {
    console.log("The error " + error.message
            + " occurred when listing the files in " + textFolder);
}

tizen.filesystem.resolve(textFolder, function(dir) {
        dir.listFiles(onsuccess, onerror);
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("Error" + e.message);
    }, "r"); // make sure to use 'r' mode as 'wgt-package' is read-only folder
```

You should see a similar log in JS console as follows:

```
js/main.js (10) :File contents: Hello World!
```