# How to play a local movie file with AVPlayer in Tizen TV App using Tizen Studio

Tags: avplayer, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-studio

I have a mp4 video file that's located in a Tizen TV app. I created an image directory and placed the mp4 file along with other images used in the app.

In Tizen IDE Rev2.4, I was able to access the file and play the video by accessing it as below.

```
/opt/user/apps/{package_id}/res/wgt/images/FILE-NAME.mp4
```

With the new updated Tizen Studio 1.1, the above path throws an invalid URI error in AVPlayer.

How can I access to the locally stored video files using JavaScript? I couldn't find any answers on Tizen developers sites.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Self solved by referencing the below solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35779530/how-to-read-resource-files-added-via-tizen-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new generated file path to the file is 
file:///opt/usr/home/owner/apps_rw/{package_id}/res/wgt/images/FILE-NAME.mp4